# How do I bind to an Event that has a delegate using Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: caliburn.micro

Usually I can bind to an event like so:

```
 cal:Message.Attach="[Event DragStarting] = [Action OnDragStarting($source,$eventArgs)]"
```

That is when an event has a signature like so:

```
public event EventHandler<DragDropCancelEventArgs> DragStarting;
```

How do I Attach to an event that has a delegate like the following:

```
 public event CanDropEventHandler IDropTargetCanDropElement;
 public delegate bool CanDropEventHandler(object sender, DropEventArgs e);
```

Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated!.

Thanks,
S

Comment: Is this a custom event you have created, in other words can you modify the signature of the delegate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why this isn't possible right away ?

Because Caliburn.Micro uses the Blend SDK's interactivity features to convert the syntax *([Event DragStarting] = [Action OnDragStarting($source,$eventArgs)])* to an [`EventTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.eventtrigger%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) and the `EventTrigger` class can't work with events that return a value, and if you think about it is logical, what to do with that return value. In general it is a bad practice for events to return values and you rarely come across such events.

> How to fix this ?

The easiest solution would be to change the delegate signature if you could to look like this:

```
public delegate void CanDropEventHandler(object sender, DropEventArgs eventArgs);
```

Then you convert that bool value returned to a public property on the `DropEventArgs` class, after that Caliburn.Micro syntax will work correctly.

> What if you can't change the delegate's signature ?

Then you will have to create an [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) by deriving from the type that owns that event or by wrapping that type if it is sealed and then declare a new event with the signature i showed you above, and then listen to the new event.

> Is there any other way ?

Maybe you can create a custom event trigger that derives from [`TriggerBase<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726538%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) which can work with events that have return values but this is an advanced technique that is a bit hard to implement, and anyway you won't to able to use CM's syntax anymore.

**Edit:** What i mean by that make the `DropEventArgs` class have that property instead of returning it from the delegate, so the `DropEventArgs` becomes something like this:

```
class DropEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public bool CanDrop {get; set;} // OR CHOOSE WHATEVER NAME YOU WANT
}
```

and the delegate becomes like i showed you above.

Comment: Hi Sniffer, Thanks for the Help!  I created my own control by inheriting from the original control successfully. I am a little confused with this line....  "Then you convert that bool value returned to a public property on the DropEventArgs class, after that Caliburn.Micro syntax will work correctly". Can you give me an example of what you mean? Thanks :-)